# How can I get it to print something when the checker turns out false for every item in a list?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, boolean, continue

I'd like to add a print("something") if the checker turns out to be false for every item in the a_list.   I'm VERY grateful for any help I can get!

```
def checker(lst, lstA):
    for i in range(4):
        if function(lst[i],lstA) != lst[i][1]: #testing FALSEHOOD
            return False;
    return True;


def main(???):
    for H in range(0,len(a_list)):
        if a_list[H] > lst[3][0]:
            continue

        lstA = [a_list[H]]

        if not checker(lst,lstA):
            continue

        lstA.append(input('some input from the user'))
        other_function(lstA)

        if lstA[1]== 40:
            print ('something something')
            return #break out of EVERY loop
```

Comment: Could you please properly indent your code so it'll be easier to understand it?

Comment: "_if the checker turns out to be false for every item in the list_". Which list do you mean? You have `a_list`, `lst`, `number_list`, and `lstA`. None of which are defined anywhere except the last one, btw.

Comment: sorry, number_list and a_list are the supposed to be the same! And I meant the a_list. What is in them doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vauge, so I am not 100% positive I am actually answering the question you were asking. Also, I am guessing the code was supposed to be indented in the following way:

```
def main(???):
    for H in range(0,len(a_list)):
        if a_list[H] > lst[3][0]:
            continue

        lstA = [number_list[i]]

        if not checker(lst,lstA):
            continue

        lstA.append(input('some input from the user'))
        other_function(lstA)

        if lstA[1]== 40:
            print ('something something')
            return #break out of EVERY loop
```

Also, you use the variable `i`, which does not seem to be defined anywhere.

You could add a variable outside of the for loop keeping track of if the check has been false for all values so far. In the beginning this should be True:

```
...
false_for_all = True
for H in range(0,len(a_list)):
...
```

Then, if the check succeeds you set it to False.

```
...
if not checker(lst,lstA):
    continue
false_for_all = True
...
```

Now you can use the `false_for_all` variable to check if the check failed for all values.

Comment: I still don't understand quite how.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where you want to add *print("something")*. If you want to add the statement in the `checker` function, you may add an indicator to store how many times the check fails:

```
def checker(lst, lstA):
    errors = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if function(lst[i],lstA) != lst[i][1]: #testing FALSEHOOD
            errors += 1
    if not errors:
        return True
    elif errors == 4:
        # print something here

    return False
```

Comment: that's not quite what I was after but I managed to solve it anyway! 
thank you though!